# What 70/80's movie ended with a boy & a girl in a flying motor home?

Tags: story-identification

Okay so this is long shot. When I was a kid I watched a movie that I have hunted for over the years. I cannot remember the plot or cast.

What I remember is two children (a boy and a girl) who had to reach somewhere with the assistance of an adult. Somehow they had super powers of a sort. I remember them walking through the carcass of what I would call a huge worm (it reminds me of sand-worms from Frank Herbert's Dune series).

I then remember the ending which is a shot of a flying motor home flying into an amazing sunset scene.

I am not sure if it was a series or movie. The motor home is a generic motor home and not futuristic. I seem to recall that the children made this fly. I seem to remember desert scenes at night. That's it and I hope that someone can help.

Comment: Sounds like Escape to Witch Mountain, the 1975 version

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like [Escape to Witch Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_to_Witch_Mountain_(1975_film))

```
two children (a boy and a girl) who had to reach somewhere with the
assistance of an adult.
```

From Wikipedia:

> The movie centers upon the brother and sister pair Tony and Tia....
>   ...they face difficulties stemming from their strange psychic/psionic
>   abilities: Tony can psychokinetically move and control inanimate
>   objects with the aid of his harmonica, while Tia can communicate
>   telepathically to Tony, commune empathically with animals, and
>   experience premonitions. Tia also possesses minor telekinetic
>   abilities.

and

> Tia and Tony hide out in a green-and-white Winnebago motor home owned
>   by a crotchety widower named Jason O'Day (Eddie Albert). Initially
>   negative toward the children, Jason gradually begins to recognize
>   their powers and the truth of their story; Tia's vague memories of a
>   disaster at sea intrigue him. He agrees to take the children....

This I do not remember, nor can I find a reference to it:

```
I remember them walking through the carcass of what I would call a
huge worm
```

It could just be that I haven't seen the movie for, um, 30-odd years.

But I do remember this:

```
the ending which is a shot of a flying motor home flying into an
amazing sunset scene.
```

[The movie’s IMDB FAQ](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0072951/faq#.2.1.9) confirms:

> They drive away, but Deranian and the police follow them in cars while
>   Bolt follows in a helicopter. A few car wrecks later, the camper flies
>   into the air where it travels alongside Bolt's helicopter. The camper
>   lands in a field, and Uncle Bené (Denver Pyle) comes walking out...

Comment: Thanks for that, I recently (in the last few moments) found this on imdb, however I am sure that they had to traverse a desert where worms were a major hazard and to avoid them they had to go inside one. I could be wrong and this is from another movie though. I will watch Escape to Witch Mountain and get back to you.

Comment: I have just skipped through the film EtoWM and unfortunately it is not the film

Comment: Not fond of the edit which ambiguate the OP's text from "answer" quotes.I realize the 'code' quotes are clunky but it's less confusing that way.